# Could not parse configuration: /hibernate.cfg.xml in my application

Tags: java, xml, hibernate

I am trying to do a CRUD operation in hibernate. i  have written the following steps for my application.
hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">
        org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
    </property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
        com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    </property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
        jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate
    </property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">
        root
    </property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">
        root
    </property>
    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</property>
    <mapping resource="Employee.hbm.xml" />
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

This is my Employee.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
 "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
    <hibernate-mapping>
   <class name="com.bullraider.crud.Employee" table="emp1000">
    <meta attribute="class-description"> This class contains employee details. </meta>
    <id name="empno" type="long" column="empno">
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="ename" type="string" column="ename" not-null="true" />
    <property name="job" type="string" column="job" not-null="true" />
    <property name="sal" type="integer" column="sal" not-null="true" />
    <property name="deptno" type="integer" column="deptno"
        not-null="true" />
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

This is my persistance class

```
public class Employee implements Serializable{

private long empno;
private String ename;
private int sal;
private String job;
private int deptno ;


public long getEmpno() {
    return empno;
}
public void setEmpno(long empno) {
    this.empno = empno;
}
public String getEname() {
    return ename;
}
public void setEname(String ename) {
    this.ename = ename;
}
public int getSal() {
    return sal;
}
public void setSal(int sal) {
    this.sal = sal;
}
public String getJob() {
    return job;
}
public void setJob(String job) {
    this.job = job;
}
public int getDeptno() {
    return deptno;
}
public void setDeptno(int deptno) {
    this.deptno = deptno;
}

}
```

This is my util class

```
   import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
   import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class HibernateUtil {

private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;
static {
    try {
        sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure()
                .buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        System.err.println("SessionFactory creation failed" + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}
   }
```

This is driver Class

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import com.bullraider.crud.util.*;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

 Main m = new Main();
        m.saveEmployee("Alex", "MANAGER", 50000, 10);
    m.saveEmployee("Mike", "CLERK", 1000, 30);
    m.saveEmployee("Tom", "SALESMAN", 2000, 10);
//      m.retriveEmployee();
//      m.deleteEmployee();
//      m.updateEmployee();
    }

    public void saveEmployee(String ename, String job, int sal, int deptno) {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction transaction = null;
    try {
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        Employee emp = new Employee();
        emp.setEname(ename);
        emp.setJob(job);
        emp.setSal(sal);
        emp.setDeptno(deptno);
        session.save(emp);
        transaction.commit();
        System.out.println("Records inserted sucessessfully");
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        transaction.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
}

public void retriveEmployee() {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction transaction = null;
    try {
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        List employee = session.createQuery("from emp1000").list();
        for (Iterator iterator = employee.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            Employee employee1 = (Employee) iterator.next();
            System.out.println(employee1.getEmpno() + "  "
                    + employee1.getEname() + "  " + employee1.getJob()
                    + "   " + employee1.getSal() + "   "
                    + employee1.getDeptno());
        }
        transaction.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        transaction.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
}

public void deleteEmployee() {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction transaction = null;
    try {
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        String queryString = "from emp1000 where deptno = :deptno";
        Query query = session.createQuery(queryString);
        query.setInteger("deptno", 30);
        Employee employee = (Employee) query.uniqueResult();
        session.delete(employee);
        System.out.println("One employee is deleted!");

        // Another way to write it
        /*
         * String hql = "delete from Employee insurance where deptno = 30";
         * Query query1 = session.createQuery(hql); int row =
         * query1.executeUpdate(); if (row == 0){
         * System.out.println("Doesn't deleted any row!"); } else{
         * System.out.println("Deleted Row: " + row); }
         */
        System.out.println("One employee is deleted!");
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        transaction.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
}

public void updateEmployee() {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction transaction = null;
    try {
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        String queryString = "from emp1000 where sal = :sal";
        Query query = session.createQuery(queryString);
        query.setInteger("sal", 8000);
        Employee employee = (Employee) query.uniqueResult();
        employee.setSal(11000);
        session.update(employee);
        System.out.println("One employee is updated!");
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        transaction.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: What doesn't work? What's the error message? What do you want from us?!

Comment: SessionFactory creation failedorg.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not parse configuration: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
 at com.bullraider.crud.util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:15)
 at com.bullraider.crud.Main.saveEmployee(Main.java:24)
 at com.bullraider.crud.Main.main(Main.java:15)

Comment: this is the error message

Comment: is file in your classpath (under src/)?

Comment: yes sir it is under src com.bullraider.crud -->Employee.java & Main.java AND com.bullraider.crud.util--->HibernateUtil.java

Comment: SessionFactory sf = new Configuration()
    .configure("/hibernate.cfg.xml")
    .buildSessionFactory();
File name is spelled correctly (filename on hdd, I mean)?

Comment: yes bellabax it is hibernate.cfg.xml that i  created

Comment: Thanks bellabax for help new Configuration() .configure("/hibernate.cfg.xml") .buildSessionFactory(); this i have to change with my code .but there is more issues only insert operation is going not the others